# Intuition for Theorem 1.46 in Evan's Measure theory and fine properties of functions, 2nd

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

In Evan's Measure theory and fine properties of functions, 2nd, after proving a weak form of the disintegration theorem, the author states the following paragraph:

> A weakly convergent sequence $f_k \rightharpoonup f$ need not converge almost
> everywhere, even if we pass to a subsequence. It is possible for example
> that the functions $f_k$ may oscillate more and more rapidly as $k \to \infty$.
> We can however introduce measures $\nu_x$ to “record” these oscillations
> near almost every point $x$.

Then he states the theorem

> Suppose that $U$ is bounded and the sequence $\{f_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded in $L^{\infty}(U;\mathbb{R}^{m})$. Then there exist a subsequence $\{f_{k_j}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}\subseteq\{f_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ and, for $\mathcal{L}^n$-a.e. $x\in U$, a Radon measure $\nu_x$ on $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $$\nu_x(\mathbb{R}^m) = 1$$ and $$F(f_{k_j})\rightharpoonup \overline{F}\ \equiv \int_{\mathbb{R}^m}F(y)d\nu_x$$
> weakly in $L^2(U)$ for each continous function $F$ on $\mathbb{R}^m$.

What is the intuition for this theorem? Additionally, I don't know how it connects to the paragraph before since it doesn't start with an assumption of some sort of weak convergence. Thank you in advance for any help.